# Is this set a pairwise disjoint?

Tags: combinatorics

> Given that there are 100 elements in $A_1$ , 1000 elements in $A_2$ , and
>   10,000 elements in $A_3$, find the number of elements in $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3$ in
>   each of the following cases.
>
> (a) $A_1 ⊆ A_2$ and $A_2 ⊆ A_3$ ;
>
> (b) the sets are pairwise disjoint;
>
> (c) there are 2 elements common to each pair of sets and 1 element in
>   all three sets.
>
> Draw, and use, relevant Venn diagrams in each case.

This my working out:

a) $A_1 ⊆A_2 \implies A_1 \cup A_2 = A_2$ 
and $A_2 ⊆A_3 \implies A_2 \cup A_3 = A_3$

Therefore: $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \overset{\tiny\text{(associative property)}}= (A_1 \cup A_2) \cup A_3 \overset{\tiny\text{(see above)}}= A_2 \cup A_3 \overset{\tiny\text{(see again above)}}= A_3$, so the union is the set A3 and therefore contains 10000 elements.

b) the sets are pairwise disjoint 
By the inclusion-exclusion principle, where N(X) = the number of elements in the finite set X

$\begin{align}N(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3) ~=~& {N(A_1) + N(A_2) + N(A_3) \\- N(A_1 \cap A_2) - N(A_1 \cap A_3) - N(A_2 \cap A_3) \\+ N(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3)}\\ ~\overset{\tiny\text{(Since they're pairwise disjoint, any intersection is the empty set)}}{\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad=}~& N(A_1) + N(A_2) + N(A_3) - 0 - 0 - 0 + 0 \\ ~=~& 100 + 1000 + 10000 \\~=~& 11100\text{ elements}\end{align}$

c) Using the inclusion-exclusion principle again:

$\begin{align}N(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3) ~=~& {N(A_1) + N(A_2) + N(A_3) \\- N(A_1 \cap A_2) - N(A_1 \cap A_3) - N(A_2 \cap A_3) \\+ N(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3)}\\ =~& 100 + 1000 + 10000 - 2 - 2 - 2 + 1 \\ =~& 11100 - 5 \\=~& 11095\end{align}$

**However I am not sure how to convey this through Venn Diagrams.
Also, can someone tell me if this correct. 
Thanks :)**

Comment: Fo c), use inclusion exclusion principle ! (but in b) is not necessary, since If $A_i$ are disjoint, then $|A_1\cup...\cup A_n|=|A_1|+...+|A_n|$.)

Comment: so there is no need to use inclusion exclusion principle for b)? but it is needed for c?

Comment: As stated in the problem, **draw a Venn diagram**. You know how a Venn diagram of three sets looks, right? Then then information in the problem tells you that certain areas in the Venn diagram are empty or have a specific number of elements in them, and then you can puzzle out what the number of elements in the _other_ areas must be one by one, such as to make the total sizes of each set come out right.

Comment: No for b) but yes for c)

Comment: There is no need to use symbolic inclusion-exclusion at all if you do as you're told and use a Venn diagram.

Comment: How would you convey the answer through Venn Diagrams? Use different colours to express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers are correct if you were asked to obtain them through symbolic logic.  However you were asked to obtain them via Venn Diagrams.

a) The Venn Diagram for $A_1\subseteq A_2\subseteq A_3$ is simply a set of  matryoshka-doll style ovals (or elipses); with the smaller sets entirely enclosed inside the larger. $$\require{enclose}\color{red}{\enclose{circle}{\color{green}{\enclose{circle}{\color{blue}{\enclose{circle}{A_1}}A_2}}A_3}}$$

b) For Pairwise Disjoint, you already know this means that the sets have no intersections.  Draw three non-intersecting ovals.

c) For this you have three sets intersecting with given overlap sizes.  You have enough information to determine the size of all seven disjoint areas of the union.